# How to create an instance of a Swagger model from a class/package with @Paths?

Tags: java, rest, swagger

I have a class with Path annotation and methods:

```
@Path("/service")
class Service
  @Path("/getSomething")
  @GET
  Response getSomething() {
    ...
  }
}
```

How do I use swagger to parse the class and create an instance of a [Swagger class](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-models/src/main/java/io/swagger/models/Swagger.java)?

* What about parsing complete packages into a Swagger model?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the Swagger [`@Api`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X#api) annotation to your resource class. Additionally, you will want to add other annotations such as `@ApiOperation`, `@ApiResponse`, etc. to document the other aspects of your API.

As far as scanning a whole package, you will want to reference your resource package when initializing your `BeanConfig`. Below is the sample code snippet from the Swagger setup [wiki](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5#using-the-application-class).

```
public class SampleApplication extends Application {

    public SampleApplication() {
        BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.2");
        beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http"});
        beanConfig.setHost("localhost:8002");
        beanConfig.setBasePath("/api");
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage("io.swagger.resources");
        beanConfig.setScan(true);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        // set your resources here
    }
}
```

**Edit (2016-02-12):** Based on the API, there is a `getSwagger()` method that you can invoke on your `BeanConfig` instance that should return the `Swagger` model you are looking for.

```
Swagger swagger = beanConfig.getSwagger();
```

You will most likely need to set the desired resource package and scan first in order for the model to be populated.

Comment: What do you do to initiate the scanning and creation of the Swagger Object?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka Assuming you already have all of the necessary Swagger JARs in your deployment assembly, you will also need to [add some Swagger specific resources](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5#using-a-custom-application-subclass). These examples are Jersey specific but Swagger offers alternative documentation for other implementations. Once setup, you should be able to retrieve the `swagger.json` or `swagger.yaml` specification at the context root of your application.

Comment: I don't want `swagger.json` nor `swagger.yaml`. I'd like to find a way to get an instance of `Swagger`. Some thing like `Swagger swagger = ...`

Comment: Thanks for try though :)

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka Oops, I misunderstood the original question. I updated my answer. Maybe this will help. :)